# Indexing a pandas dataframe by integer

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find an elegant way to [index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) by an integer index.
In the following example I want to get the value 'a' from the first element of the `'A'` column.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'A':['a','b', 'c'], 'B':['f', 'g', 'h']}, 
    index=[10,20,30]
    )
```

I would expect `df['A'].ix[0]` and `df['A'][10]` both  to return `'a'`. 
The `df['A'][10]` does return `'a'`, but `df['A'].ix[0]` throws a `KeyError: 0`. The only way I could think of to get the value `'a'` based on the index 0 is to use the following approach.

```
df['A'][df['A'].index[0]]
```

Is there a shorter way to get `'a'` out of the dataframe, using the 0 index?

**Update**

As of pandas 0.11 there is a another way to [index by integer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer).

```
df.iloc[0] # integer based, gives the first row
df.loc[10] # label based, gives the row with label 10
```

This [supersedes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecations) the `irow` approach .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get an error with `df['A'].ix[0]` because your indexing doesn't start at 0, it starts at 10. You can get the value you want with either of the following

```
df['A'].ix[10]
df['A'].irow(0)
```

The first uses by the correct index. The second command, which I suspect is what you want, finds the value by the row number, rather than by index value, and is technically only two characters longer than if `df['A'].ix[0]` worked.

Alternatively, you can reset the indices so that they will respond the way you expect for `df['A'].ix[0]`:

```
df2=df.reset_index()
```

This will preserve your old indices (10, 20, etc.) by moving them into a column called "index" in the df2 data frame. Then `df2['A'].ix[0]` will return 'a'. If you want to remove the old 10-based indices, you can insert the flag `drop=True` into the parenthesis of the reset_index function.

Comment: I think it is `df['A'].iget(0)` because `df['A']` is a `Series`, which has no `irow`.

Comment: irow() is deprecated. Use iloc[] for position based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

In newer pandas version u can also use df["A"].iat(0).