# python, x in list and x == list[28] deliver different results

Tags: python, list

Im trying to find if some string is in a list. when using: `'if string in list'` i get a `false`. but when im trying `'if string == list[28]'` i get a `true`.

how come? the string is definitely in the list.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import re

nba_df=pd.read_csv("assets/nba.csv")
cities=pd.read_html("assets/wikipedia_data.html")[1]
cities=cities.iloc[:-1,[0,3,5,6,7,8]]
nba_df = nba_df[(nba_df['year'] == 2018)]
nba_df['team'] = nba_df['team'].apply(lambda x: x.split('*')[0])
nba_df['team'] = nba_df['team'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
nba_df['team'] = nba_df['team'].str.strip()

cityList = cities['Metropolitan area'].str.strip()

actualCities = []
for idx, city in enumerate(nba_df['team']):
    if city == 'New Orleans Pelicans':
        print('string: ', city.split()[0] + ' ' + city.split()[1])
        print('cityList[28]: ', cityList[28])
        print('is string in list: ', (city.split()[0] + ' ' + city.split()[1]) in cityList)
        print('is string == list[28]: ', (city.split()[0] + ' ' + city.split()[1]) == cityList[28])
```

output:

```
string:  New Orleans
cityList[28]:  New Orleans
is string in list:  False
is string == list[28]:  True
```

Comment: You **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: My guess is that you're effectively doing this now: `(city.split()[0] + ' ') + (city.split()[1] in cityList)`. So I'm guessing you want this instead: `(city.split()[0] + ' ' + city.split()[1]) in cityList`

Comment: What is the exact value of cityList[28]? I try to reproduce but can't

Comment: Can you please tell what is the value of list[28] / cityList[28]. Your question is incomplete.

Comment: sorry, if did pose a very clear question. hadnt posted here anything in years. i tried to add brackets as Wolph suggested. unfortunately it didnt help. value of cityList[28] is New Orleans. I added a line that prints it. hope that helps

Comment: This result is unexpected. Can you share your whole code?

Comment: i added the code which comes before the weird behaviour. the data comes from a file. shall i also post it here somewhere?

Comment: Yes, a [mre] needs to include input data. It would be best if you just provided the Python data (`cityList`) rather than CSV plus processing code. To demonstrate the issue, it looks like you just need the last four lines, with `city = 'New Orleans Pelicans'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your issue is related to membership testing with the `in` operator, particularly as it relates to `pandas` "containers" such as DataFrames and Series. Keep in mind when you say:

> how come? the string is definitely in the list.

This is not quite accurate. Your `cityList` is a `Series` object, not a `list`. This creates some quirks we have to work around, since we cannot treat a `Series` the same as a list. In general `Series` behave a bit more like a `dictionary` rather than a list.

I've created a truncated test example for your code, using the setup here:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Teams": [ "Boston Celtics", "Brooklyn Nets", "New York Knicks", "Philadelphia 76ers", "Toronto Raptors", "Chicago Bulls", "Cleveland Cavaliers", "Detroit Pistons", "Indiana Pacers", "Milwaukee Bucks", "Atlanta Hawks", "Charlotte Hornets", "Miami Heat", "Orlando Magic", "Washington Wizards", "Denver Nuggets", "Minnesota Timberwolves", "Oklahoma City Thunder", "Portland Trail Blazers", "Utah Jazz", "Golden State Warriors", "Los Angeles Clippers", "Los Angeles Lakers", "Phoenix Suns", "Sacramento Kings", "Houston Rockets", "Memphis Grizzlies", "San Antonio Spurs", "New Orleans Pelicans" ],
    "Cities": [ "Boston", "Brooklyn", "New York", "Philadelphia", "Toronto", "Chicago", "Cleveland", "Detroit", "Indiana", "Milwaukee", "Atlanta", "Charlotte", "Miami", "Orlando", "Washington", "Denver", "Minnesota", "Oklahoma City", "Portland", "Utah", "Golden", "Los Angeles", "Los Angeles", "Phoenix", "Sacramento", "Houston", "Memphis", "San Antonio", "New Orleans" ]
}

nba_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Teams', 'Cities'])
# doing this to mimic your code of storing the Series to cityList
cityList = nba_df['Cities'].str.strip()

print(cityList)
print(type(cityList))
```

Output:

```
0            Boston
1          Brooklyn
2          New York
...
28      New Orleans
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

The key is to use `cityList.values`, rather than just `cityList`. However, I encourage you to read the [`Series.values` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html), as Pandas does not recommend using this property anymore (it looks like `Series.array` was added in 0.24, and they recommend using that instead). Both `PandasArray` and `numpy.ndarray` appear to behave a bit more like a `list`, at least in this example when it comes to membership test. Again, reading the [`Series.array` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.array.html#pandas.Series.array) is highly encouraged.

Example from the terminal:

```
>>> cityList[28]
'New Orleans'
>>> 'New Orleans' in cityList
False
>>> 'New Orleans' in cityList.values
True
>>> 'New Orleans' in cityList.array
True
```

You could also just create a list from your `cityList` (which again, is a `Series`)

```
>>> list(cityList)
['Boston', 'Brooklyn', ..., 'New Orleans']
>>> 'New Orleans' in list(cityList)
True
```

**Side Note**

I would probably rename your `cityList` to `citySeries` or something similar, to make a note in your code that you are not dealing with a list, but a "special" container from the `pandas` library.

Alternatively, you could just create your `cityList` like so (**note:** I'm using your code now, not my example):

```
cityList = list(cities['Metropolitan area'].str.strip())
```

---

I did have to do a bit of research for this answer as I am by no means a `pandas` expert, so here are the three questions that helped me figure this out:

- [Indexing a pandas dataframe by integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11621165/15744261)
- [membership test in pandas data frame column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42268549/15744261)
- [How does the "in" and "not in" statement work in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45707721/15744261)

Comment: Thanks Aelarion for the detailed answer!

Comment: Happy to help! :)